# splitChunks optimization resulting in a larger bundle size?

Tags: javascript, webpack, nuxt.js

I'm trying to optimize the build for my application, here is what it looks like with the default config,
[image]

Now, I've made a few changes to my `node_mdoules`, removed about 5-6 unused packages, replaced `sanitize-html` with `isomorphic-dompurify` which should *ideally* result in a smaller bundle size, but this is what it looks like now,

[image]

Even though the size of the `vendor` and `app` chunks are down significantly - 62kb and 28kb respective, the "All" size is up from 1.64mb to 1.79mb (~150kb), the only change in the nuxt config is adding the `splitChunks` config to `build`,

```js
build: {
  ..
  splitChunks: {
    layouts: true
  }
}
```

Why does this happen? and is it okay if the overall bundle size is larger when `layouts` is split?

Will it affect performance negatively?